# Is there a web app HLA assembler?

Tags: assembly, web-applications, hla

HLA is an easy enough language to install on virtually any platform, but I have a friend who is attempting to learn it on a machine on which she does not have administrative privileges. I've bumped into online compilers for NASM (recognizing that "compiler" is not *strictly* the right word), and I'm curious whether anyone has bumped into an online HLA?

The answer might well be "no", in which case NASM will have to do. All suggestions are appreciated. (She'll hopefully have a Raspberry Pi around anyway in a few months, or at least a cheap laptop.)

Comment: Never used HLA, but why would it need admin privileges? The installation guide specifically says _you can put the file wherever you like_.

Comment: Interesting, I'm accustomed to using it on Linux. My friend has a Win7 machine. I know that on Linux it would require a sudo to install; Win7, I'm not so sure about. Are you saying that the file itself is available for download?

Comment: Not sure which HLA you are talking about, [this](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/HighLevelAsm/WinDownload.html) was the first I found using google.